# Export azure ad groups membership via powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I need help in the powershell script. I am looking to get Azure AD, group membership details for multiple groups which are in the CSV file.

The format, I am looking to get is:

Group Name :SG-Test-Users
Members: xyz, abc etc

[Output needed in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCZvs.png)

Please help

I tried, below script but it is not giving an output in the format I am looking for.

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\testgroup.csv" | ForEach-Object {Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $_.name | select displayname,userprincipalname} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\outputfile1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try the command below, it works fine on my side. **Note** it will append data to the file instead of overwriting.

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\testgroup.csv"
foreach ($line in $csv){
    $groupname = $line.GroupName
    $objectid = (Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $groupname}).ObjectId
    Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $objectid | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\outputfile1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

**My test file**:

testgroup.csv

[image]

outputfile1.csv

[image]

Comment: Actually, i wanted an output to have a "Group Name" column also and then group members. The output with this only shows the member names and it is difficult to match with group.

Comment: Someone please help to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, but here's my take

try below (modify output as required) and then save the console output to file and massage as required in excel

cheers

```
    $gg=Get-AzureADGroup -top 200
    ForEach ($g in $gg){
        $a = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $g.ObjectId  
        $b = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $g.ObjectId -All $true 
        ForEach ($c in $b){ 
            Write-host  $a.DisplayName ";" $c.ObjectId ";" $c.ObjectType $c.UserType ";" $c.UserPrincipalName 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ResourceAuditArray = @()
ForEach ($g in Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "<first word of groups e.g. DFC, ADF, DAS>"){ 
    $ResourceAuditArray += Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $g.ObjectId -All $true  | Select-Object ObjectId, ObjectType, UserType, UserPrincipalName, @{n="DisplayName"; e={$g.DisplayName}}
} 

$ResourceAuditArray | Export-Csv  "<AAD Users list>.Csv"
```