# Azure AD Powershell Script to export group membership

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I need help in creating a PowerShell script to import user accounts from a CSV file and export Azure username + group membership in the below format :

> A)    UserName: Jdoe_3
>
> Groups assigned : Subscription-Owners
>
> B)    UserName: Jill
>
> Groups assigned : Subscription-Readers

As an example, a command for getting group membership is:
 `get-azureaduser -searchstring abc@contoso.com | Get-AzureADUserMembership | select DisplayName`

Comment: so ... where is your code & what is NOT working as expected? [*grin*]

Comment: There is a similar case for you, you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192881/export-azure-ad-groups-membership-via-powershell?rq=1).

Comment: Hi Sunny, the output does not show the group name with displayname. When i will run query for 100 groups, i would like to know the which member belongs to which group.

Comment: I was able to get it working with the below script however can you help me in changing the output so the GroupName, DisplayName and UPN should show up in different columns in the csv file.

Comment: $csv = Import-Csv "C:\temp\testgroup.csv"
foreach ($line in $csv){
    $groupname = $line.GroupName
    $objectid = (Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $groupname}).ObjectId
    $a = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $ObjectId
    $b = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $objectid
    ForEach ($c in $b){ 
    $a.DisplayName , $c.DisplayName , $c.UserPrincipalName | Out-File "c:\temp\whosttest.csv" -Append
    }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code below, the new csv file "whosttest.csv" can has the 3 columns you said:

```
       $csv = Import-Csv "C:\temp\testgroup.csv" 

        $temp =@()

        foreach ($line in $csv)
       { 
        $groupname = $line.GroupName 
        $objectid = (Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $groupname}).ObjectId
        $a = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $ObjectId 
        $b = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $objectid 
        ForEach ($c in $b)
                { 
                 $temp += New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    'GroupName' = $a.DisplayName
                    'DisplayName'=$c.DisplayName
                     'UPN' =$c.UserPrincipalName
                 }

                 } 
        }

       $temp | Export-Csv "c:\temp\whosttest.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!